# Cryptic Country 3

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I've owned a place with a contradictory name

The snow queen has helped give me some freezing fame

Change two letters in a non-poem for the currency of mine

Unearthing all my *reges* really feels just fine

Split into 3 sectors with names strange to strangers

My people are like a pastry, but with no take-the-piss danger

Change a letter in a heavenly body for my minister's identity

The first four letters of my capital help you deal with plenty

Name the country

Comment: Could the snow queen refer to Rot13([Dhrra Ryfn](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Elsa_the_Snow_Queen))?

Comment: That isn't what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The country must be

> Denmark

I've owned a place with a contradictory name

> Greenland is not very green.

The snow queen has helped give me some freezing fame

> [The snow queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snow_Queen) inspired [Frozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_(2013_film)).

Change two letters in a non-poem for the currency of mine

> prose -> krone

Unearthing all my reges really feels just fine

> 

Split into 3 sectors with names strange to strangers

> 

My people are like a pastry, but with no take-the-piss danger

> Danish

Change a letter in a heavenly body for my minister's identity

> Mars -> Lars, Prime Minister of Denmark

The first four letters of my capital help you deal with plenty

> **Cop**enhagen

Comment: The great Riley himself